# Is "Let's get started" passive voice or not?

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles, get-passive

Is the idiomatic expression 'get started' (as in "Let's get started") a passive construction?

Or is 'started' here an adjective?

### EDIT

As John Lawler has suggested in his answer, let's not get carried away with "Let's". Think of the title "Let's get started" as merely one example construction incorporating 'get started', as clearly shown in the question itself by "as in".

Also, I think the real issue here is whether "get started" denotes the "come to be in a started state" as John Lawler says in his answer. If it does, I'm sure there's no way it is a passive construction. But does it?

I mean, to my non-native ears, "Let's get started" means "Let's start", which is proven by the fact that they are easily interchangeable in any context. So, if "get started" is equivalent to "start" in meaning, how come it means "come to be in a started state"?

Comment: It's an adverb.

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/start) merely lists 'get started' in this sense as a multi-word synonym of 'begin'. The get-passive is identical in form (the machine got started by the engineers when they arrived), but the usage in 'Let's get started' has no implication of an outside agency. 'Let's get going' is a close synonym.

Comment: @Ricky Can 'get' ever be followed by an adverb? *_I got angrily._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought one of the reasons for using the passive voice was you wouldn't want to reveal the agent or you didn't know about the agent.

Comment: @JK2: "Angry" in that case would be an adverbish mongrel, as the poet said.

Comment: @Ricky I don't know what you mean by that. But are you at least saying that it's not a passive construction?

Comment: @JK2: Probably not.

Comment: There is quite a difference between not wishing to reveal an agent and there not being any agent. 'The machine got started' hides the engineers (or whoever), but 'Let's get started' just means 'Let's begin'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Granted, it's a good point, but I don't know where you got this idea of, on the one hand, allowing a passive voice when you know of an agent but doesn't wish to reveal, and on the other hand, disallowing a passive voice when there isn't any agent or more precisely when you don't know who the agent is.

Comment: A passive construction is a transformation of an active one: John/someone kicked the man <==> The man was/got kicked [by John/someone]. The agent is the one doing the kicking (there must be _someone_ doing the kicking, whether they're mentioned or not). Choosing to relate this event using the active or passive doesn't alter the facts. // However, 'We got started' as used in the sense you use with 'Let's get started' is **not** a transformation of 'Someone/John started us'. It's an active sentence, like 'We got dressed', 'We got  ready', 'We began', 'We started', 'We got finished'....

Comment: Yes and I don't understand how either 'get started' or 'Let's get started' could be anything but a command

You might just argue that 'the workers were told by their boss to get started' was a passive construction but how could that work as in 'Let's…'?

I also missed how it's idiomatic. Wouldn't that indicate there were other choices more widely used or more correct or both?

Comment: @JK2: Yes, "get" is followed by an adverb in "get well" (as opposed to "get good", or "git gud" as commonly spelled in the gaming subculture, that packs a very different meaning).

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-reliably-and-accurately-identify-the-passive-voice-in-writing-or-speec

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please re-read the first line of the question. Originally, I have clearly asked about the idiomatic expression 'get started' and "Let's get started" was merely an example sentence having the expression. So, I wonder how you think it's "chaning the crux of the question in mid-bounty".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can attack each and every one of your "reasons", but I don't think it's worth it. But one thing I should make clear: The only clear criterion that distinguishes between a passive construction and a mere copula construction is by meaning, if you know what I mean.

Comment: JK2 I also edited my post to reflect your edit.

Comment: The hivemind seems to have coalesced around the idea that this *isn't* passive so I'll spare myself the agita of an answer they can downvote... but they're still wrong. **Yes, *get started* is grammatically passive**. Semantically, "let's get started" and "let's begin" are used interchangeably and there's no meaningful difference but—as @RaceYouAnytime illustrated while attempting to deny it—the causative agent in "let's get started by introducing ourselves" is actually the introduction. Grammatically, you're stating that we should reach a "started state"...

Comment: ...of course, that involves us actually doing something. As far as why say it that way, to native speakers it sounds more welcoming and less like an order than "Let's start".

Comment: @ily Convinced that the OP's example is passive, but  also  convinced an answer of yours would be downvoted. What happened to  intellectual integrity? What happened to actually helping the OP? Who is more important here?

Comment: Closely related: [“To start” vs “to get started”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/to-start-vs-to-get-started) and [Let's get started! or let's get going?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309177/lets-get-started-or-lets-get-going) and [Can I replace 'get started on' with 'start'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371245/can-i-replace-get-started-on-with-start)

Comment: Here's an answer that states: [*"To start" is an active construction, while "to get started" is a passive one*.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3988/44619)

Comment: Retracted downvote, and deleted previous comment criticising your edit. I realise that you didn't officially award the bounty to anyone,(or did you forget ?) but RUA's answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 7):

In the expression "Let's get started," *started* functions as a ***[participial adjective](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20participal%20adjective&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS734US735&oq=define%20participal%20adj)***.

> an adjective that is a participle in origin and form, such as *burned*, *cutting*, *engaged*.

Consider the phrase

> Let's get *drunk*.

Here, we use an adjective, *drunk*, to describe how we are going to get.  It modifies "us," as we see when we remove the contraction:

> Let *us* get drunk.

"Start" is a verb in this context, but "started" is being used as an adjective to describe "us."  So we call it a participial adjective.

I would not describe this as a passive construction.  Because *Let us get started* is an imperative statement, there is an implied subject.

> **You** let us get started

This construction, with the implied subject, is a standard active voice construction.  We can see how it would look in passive voice by swapping the subject and object:

> *We* are allowed to get started *by you*.

But as it stands, the sentence is in an active voice, and *started* functions as a participle, or *participial adjective*.

Comment: Similarly: Let’s get ready. Let’s get high. Let’s get closer. Let’s get killed. Let's get naughty. Let's get down to business. Let’s get lost. Let’s get going. Let’s get out of here. Let’s get married. Let’s get together. But: Let’s get *it* started and Let’s get *you* home.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Your _exhaust_ example is, I think, a different animal. Verbs like _exhaust_ involves the meaning of a certain state of mind or body, so the construction 'get exhausted' can entail "come to be in an exhausted state" as well as the passive action of exhausting, entirely depending on context. On the other hand, I doubt that 'get started', contrary to what John Lawler seems to argue, can entail or even implicate "come to be in a started state", but it can only entail or implicate the passive action of starting, even though the "passive" part might not be apparent in context.

Answer (score 7):

Let's leave out the *Let's*, shall we? It just adds another idiom to contend with.

*Get started* is a normal [causative/inchoative use of *get*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59744/15299).
Since *get* can be the causative/inchoative of **either** *be* or *have*, we have two possibilities:

**Be**:

- *He got tired = He became tired = He came to **be** tired.* (inchoative of *be*, intransitive)
- *I got him tired = I caused him to become tired.* (causative of *be*, transitive)

**Have**:

- *He got a new car = He came to **have** a new car* (inchoative of *have*, intransitive)
- *I got him a new car = I caused him to come to have a new car* (causative of *have*, transitive)

In the case of *get started*, it's both *be* and *have*. Since *get started* means 'come to be in a started state', it works fine with *be*. But since that state in addition arrives at a state of 'having started', a Perfect construction, there is no contrast. Things often work out like this with idioms.

Oh, as for the original question, no, it's not a Passive; if anything, it's a Perfect, as noted. The confusable *get* Passive occurs when *get* means *come to be*, as in *get married, get arrested, get drunk*. This works best, as you note, with predicate adjectives derived from past participles of transitive verbs, where the difference between a true participle and a derived adjective is irrelevant. So call it an adjective if you like, but since you can't tell the difference in this example, calling it a Passive invokes a rule that is not obviously involved.

---

EDIT: There are a number of issues tied up with this question about the Passive.

First, let's dispose of the Imperative. *Let's get started* can certainly be an order, if uttered by the right person in the right circumstances. Even if not, it's clearly an impositive, with the speaker attempting to impose a course of action on the addressee(s). That's because of *Let's*, which always functions as an impositive, even if only a suggestion, and always includes both the speaker and the addressee in the invitation, for a joint action. This is one of the very few places where English categorically requires a first person plural **inclusive** reading of *us*.

Second, the confusing issue with *get started* is that **both** *get* **and** *start* are inchoatives.
That is, they both refer to the **beginning** of something -- an action or a state.
But in this case, not the same something. *Get* has wide scope, while *start* has narrow scope,
so what is to *start* is some joint task that is unbegun so far (say, making supper). In order to start that task -- in order to get started on that task, or to get going on that task, and eventually to get finished with that task -- it is necessary for someone to do something preparatory, like going into the kitchen, setting the table, going to the bakery, etc.

So *get started* means to do what is necessary in order to start the project. When one *has gotten started* (American pple of *get*), one has passed the boundary into the action or state, so one *has started*, and if the action is not punctual or the state not ephemeral, then one has entered into the event or the state that has begun.

This is not what I would call *Passive*. Given [the vast ignorance of what 'Passive' means in English](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/passive_loathing.pdf) among the English-speaking, -learning, and -teaching communities, I hesitate to use the term *Passive* for anything that does not require an application of the Passive-formation rule to a verb phrase. And this doesn't. It does require a past participle, but that isn't the same as Passive.

One would only get a Passive reading of "get started" if one had used the causative -- therefore transitive -- sense of *start*, as in *start the race*. Then the race would have been started (by the unmentioned causers), and that's a Passive for sure. But not normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding your last paragraph, I've edited my question to pinpoint what I think is the real issue. Please review the EDIT and hopefully edit your answer or leave a comment to address that issue.

Comment: @JK2: See edit above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Sorry that your technical analysis is just beyond me. So let me get this straight. I think I can say either _I started this controversy_ or _this controversy got started by me_ to basically mean the same thing. And do you still think that the latter is NOT a passive construction of the former? Or do you think that this is a different example of 'get started' from the one in the OP (even without "Let's")?

Comment: With the verb _start_, yes, you can say both of those sentences, and they mean the same, and the second one is a _get_-Passive. _Was started_ is also Passive. Aspectual  predicates like _start, begin, finish, end, continue, repeat,_ etc. have their own peculiar syntax, because they don't mean much -- just an elaboration or specification of the event described in their complement. So they behave more like gears than pistons -- just modulating some meaning instead of providing it. As for Passive, you haven't provided your criterion for what **you** mean by "Passive".

Comment: If _this controversy got started by me_ means the same thing as _I started this controversy_, then I think it's safe to say that the former is a passive construction of the latter. And I think you would agree on this with me. So I'm asking if you think of 'get started' in the OP as something different.

Answer (score 2):

"Started" certainly looks like a passive participle. It's true it doesn't seem to have much of a passive meaning, but maybe it's subtle. To me, it seems even less like a perfect participle, so I don't think that is the explanation.

#### "Passives" are classified into two main types: stative and eventive

It seems that "passive" constructions in English can generally be divided into two types: "stative" passives and "eventive" passives. See the following ELL post: [If gone in “has been gone” is an adjective, how do I know that dispatched in “has been dispatched” is a past participle?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88624/if-gone-in-has-been-gone-is-an-adjective-how-do-i-know-that-dispatched-in-ha/88640#88640)

- The "eventive" passive is the one that is probably closer to the "core" idea that people have of what passive voice is. For any transitive verb, an eventive passive construction can be formed with a subject corresponding to what usually is the object of the transitive verb. The eventive passive construction, as the name implies, may refer to an event. An example is "The window was broken by vandals", which can be used to narrate the event of the window breaking.
- The "stative" passive is less productive, and it's more controversial to classify it as actually being "passive" voice strictly speaking. It is used to refer to states, not events, as in the sentence "The window was broken" meaning "The window was in a broken state".

There seem to be different explanations about how eventive and stative passive constructions work in terms of part-of-speech categories. However, everyone I have read seems to agree that the participial word in a "stative" passive construction is an adjective.

Disagreement seems to be about whether it is correct to see eventive passives as "verbal" passives (in contrast to stative "adjectival" passives) or whether eventive passive participles are also best analyzed as a type of adjective.

There are some diagnostic tests that eventive passives always fail, but that stative passives and normal adjectives can at least sometimes pass. The diagnostics mainly seem to be related to gradability: eventive passives cannot be gradable, while stative passives and normal adjectives may. For concrete examples of these kinds of tests, see BillJ's answer to [Is “running” a gerund or a participial adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/366957/77227); there is a quite similar distinction between different types of *-ing* participial words.

#### "Started" in "get started" doesn't look like an eventive passive

While "get started" has a generally eventive meaning, I don't think this is evidence that it includes an eventive passive construction because, as John Lawler says in his answer, it's usual for the verb "get" to contribute an inchoative meaning to a phrase that it is part of, even if the other part would have a stative meaning by itself. For example, "Let's get serious" has an eventive meaning even though "serious" is obviously a non-eventive adjective by itself.

I can't figure out any way to demonstrate that "started" is gradable in this context, so I can't use the gradability diagnostic to show that it is not an eventive passive.

However, there is possibly another test that can differentiate stative and eventive passives. “Started” in “get started” cannot be followed by a “by”-phrase, and a paper I found by Josef Fruehwald and Neil Myler about a construction that seems somewhat similar to me, the “done my homework” construction, seems to indicate that the inability to add a “by”-phrase is a diagnostic test for establishing that a construction is not an eventive passive (2.2 p. 10). (I’m not sure how reliable a diagnostic this is, or if any counterexamples exist.)

#### So it would have to be a stative passive (which are adjectival)

If the argument above establishes that it is not an eventive passive, it could still be called something like a “stative adjectival passive participle” (the term Fruehwald and Myler use to refer to “started” and analogous words in "be started my homework"-type sentences).

"Passive" and "adjective" are not necessarily mutually exclusive categories unless you narrowly define "passive" to exclude stative passive constructions, and narrowly define "adjective" to exclude passive participles in eventive passive constructions.

#### It's not a perfect

It doesn’t seem to have any connection to pefect constructions, either in sense or in grammar. The meaning of “get started” is evidently distinct from “have started,” since we can’t say “Let’s have started.” It also doesn’t behave grammatically like a perfect participle since it can be embedded in a surrounding perfect construction (I took this test from Fruehwald and Myler p. 7, which uses the same criterion to argue that “be done” is not a perfect construction):

- *They have had started. (unacceptable because of successive perfects)
- They have gotten started. (acceptable)

#### Sources:

[*I’m done my homework*- Case assignment in a stative passive](https://jofrhwld.github.io/rpaper/FruehwaldMyler_bedone.pdf), by Josef Fruehwald & Neil Myler

Answer (score 1):

**Causative, not passive?**

"Let's get started" sounds like an ellipse of "Let's get [sth.] started", for example:

> Let's get the session started.

The sentence still *looks like* a passive construction, but this is deceptive: it is not a passive.

It is NOT "we" that get started, but something, for instance a session, that gets or rather that we get started.

To disprove that we have a case of passive voice at hand, let's get the sentence modified:
If we used the verb "be", the sentence would only make sense if we said:

> The session was started.

Not:

> *We were started.

This clearly makes no sense. "To get started" is not a passive voice.

In the same vein, 'let's get drunk' is not a case of passive, but a case of a causative use of the verb "get". Why? Because 'let's get drunk' actually means:

> Let's get us/ourselves drunk.

And to prove this claim, we can change the the indirect object pronoun "us/ourselves" without altering the meaning of the verb in question:

> Let's get Joe drunk!

Comment: @JK2 I was wondering whether my answer doesn't solve your question.